# Python : Updating an array in dictionary with values from another dictionary if a key match

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to update all the values in an Array of a dictionary if a match is found for a key value. "a" is the key I am checking against.

```py
dict1={'Array1':[{'a':123,'b':456,'c':678},{'a':987,'b':654,'c':421}]}

dict2={'a':987,'b':555,'c':111}
```

Expected Output:

```
dict3={'Array1': [{'a': 123, 'b': 456, 'c': 678}, {'a': 987, 'b': 555, 'c': 111}]}
```

Since 'a':987 matched in the second array, all the values are updated from dict2.

Looking for suggestions in Python. I am thinking of creating a data frame out of both the dicts. Join them and update and then convert back to dict. Any other easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Try `update`

```py
dict1={'Array1':[{'a':123,'b':456,'c':678},{'a':987,'b':654,'c':421}]}

dict2={'a':987,'b':555,'c':111}

for data in dict1['Array1']:
    if(data['a'] == dict2['a']):
        data.update(dict2)
        
print(dict1)
```

```
{'Array1': [{'a': 123, 'b': 456, 'c': 678}, {'a': 987, 'b': 555, 'c': 111}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar: updating values in first dictionary if value is in second dictionary

```
f = dict([('one',1),('two',2),('four',4)])
s = dict(zip(['one','five','six'],[42,5,6]))

print( f )

for k,v in f.items():
    if k in s:
        f[k] = s[k]

print( f )
```